# How to Put Bullet Icon at Start of Each Line of Text

Tags: css, formatting

I'm working with an ecommerce site, and having problems styling some of the items.

They have a built in facility to list all of the product attributes. These are delivered one per line as follows:

```
<b>Brand:</b> 
<span itemprop="brand">Cosmetal</span> 
<br>

<b>Configuration:</b> 
<span class="editable" id="attribute-values_129_value" title="">Under Counter</span>
<br>
```

Is there a way for me to put a bullet icon before each line of text, given that I can no way of putting these within a p tag or anything else?

Many thanks for any pointers!

Niki

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css` to force the `span` elements to displayed like list-items:

```css
.add-bullets span {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-bullets">
  <b>Brand:</b> 
  <span itemprop="brand">Cosmetal</span> 
  <br>

  <b>Configuration:</b> 
  <span class="editable" id="attribute-values_129_value" title="">Under Counter</span>
  <br>
</div>
```

> Note that I wrapped that block with `div` element with `add-bullets` class to make sure only `span` **inside** that div will be displayed like list items (and not all the `span` elements in your page.